# Image view inside custom table view cell disappears when cell inserted into table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

This is my first time dealing with iOS development. I'm creating an app that uses a custom UITableViewCell to display information retrieved from Core Data. Im having this issue where an imageView that displays a color disappears randomly when the cell is inserted into the table. If the image view does disappear, closing the app and restarting it will fix the problem.

Right after inserting into table: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scFUo.png)
After force closing app and restarting: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08BhW.png)

Any advice on where the problem is would be appreciated.

Here is some of the relevant code. Im using NSFetchedResultsController too if that helps.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CustomTableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    self.configureCell(cell, withObject: object)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {

    let imageData: NSData = object.valueForKey("image") as! NSData
    let colorImageBlank: UIImage = UIImage(named: "blank.png")!
    let picture: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
    let date: NSDate
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

    cell.cellImage.image = picture

    let colorString = object.valueForKey("color")!.description
    var color: UIColor = UIColor()
    if colorString == "Blue" {
        color = UIColor.blueColor()
    } else if colorString == "Red" {
        color = UIColor.redColor()
    } else if colorString == "Green" {
        color = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if colorString == "Yellow" {
        color = UIColor.yellowColor()
    } else if colorString == "Orange" {
        color = UIColor.orangeColor()
    } else if colorString == "Purple" {
        color = UIColor.purpleColor()
    }

    cell.colorImage.image = colorImageBlank
    cell.colorImage.backgroundColor = color
    cell.colorImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    cell.cellImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.cellImage.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    cell.cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0


    cell.locationNameLabel.text = object.valueForKey("name")!.description
    cell.locationNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)
    cell.locationNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail

    cell.categoryLabel.text = object.valueForKey("category")!.description
    cell.categoryLabel.font = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(12.0)
    cell.categoryLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail

    date = object.valueForKey("date")! as! NSDate

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    cell.descriptionLabel.text = object.valueForKey("descript")!.description
    cell.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as! CustomTableViewCell, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
    case .Move:
        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug you configureCell method and check if object exists at that point?

Comment: So it turns out that when the cells are inserted, the image view, and the labels for the description and the date just disappear. Is this a constraint issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue of framing because not only image view two other labels for date and other label is also missing, Are you adding constraints to it?

Comment: Wow, I was so focused on the imageView not showing up that I didn't realize those labels were missing. I do have constraints on the cell, could those be the issue?

Comment: So after investigating the constraints, I found out that the issue was with the size class. I switched back to Any x Any and the layout issues were resolved!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've shared I can suggest the following:

check your configureCell method, seems like it's nil for that period of time. 
I've made such conclusion from your first screenshot: instead of text, You have placeholder specified on Your storyboard/ xib.

So, check if

```
 let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
```

returns the proper object from your fetch controller (update it, if that is not true).

Hope this helps.

Comment: SO I have debugged the configueCell method and the object does exist, but after stepping through the function, these errors show up in the console: 2016-08-01 14:14:50.664 Scrapper[4654:503178] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2016-08-01 14:14:50.664 Scrapper[4654:503178] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15) are these related to the bug?